# Why does my Velocity Template conditional assignment not work properly?

Tags: java, velocity, getter-setter, apache-velocity

I am trying to create custom Getters using Velocity Template that are annotated with a `@Generated` annotation.

My current template looks like this:

```java
#if($field.recordComponent)
@Generated
public ${field.type} ${field.name}() {
return this.${field.name};
}
#else
    #set($getterName = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($field.name))
    #if($field.boolean)
        #set($getterPrefix = "is")
    #else
        #set($getterPrefix = "get")
    #end
@Generated
public ${field.type} ${getterPrefix}${getterName}() {
return this.${field.name};
}
#end
```

Now without the whole conditional part, e.g. setting `getterPrefix` just to the boolean value of `field.boolean`, it assigns true/false to the variable correctly, and also generates the code snippet.

However, once I try to add the conditional elements with #if, #else, #end as seen in my code above, it breaks and just shows the  following error popup: 
[image]

If you have any suggestions or idea on why that might be, or how I could generally improve my VT, please feel free to respond!

Thanks in advance!